# Comparator with Hysteresis

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

[image: Circuit diagram]
The reference of the comparator is placed in that range, in particular, Vh=1.282, Vl=1.182  meaning that the hysteresis is 100mV.

But I am getting an output which is always High.

May I know why is it coming like that. Attached schematic and Simulation results.

[image: Output waveform]

Comment: U1 input`-` is 0.9V and input `+` is 1.10V or 1.40V, then shouldn't the output always be high because `in+ > in-`? Or was the U1 reference input supposed to be 1.25V instead of 0.9V?

Comment: Your refh and refl don't make sense to me given your low and high specs (they aren't in between -- and for a comparator, I'd expect them to be.) Given the desired hysteresis band, wouldn't the values be 1.75 V and 1.85 V? Looks to me like a single comparator and three standard-valued resistors. Does your input source need to be loaded down?

Comment: Plot the voltages at the (+) and (-) inputs of the comparator and you'll see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you are out of your element. I can't tell if you are taking a class or just trying to solve some problem facing you. But if I'm reading you with any accuracy, then you aren't even interpreting your specifications well.

My first *disagreement* with you is the selection of your hysteresis voltages. What does make sense to me is the magnitude of the hysteresis band, or \$100\:\text{mV}\$. Since that does make sense, I'll use it in order to move forward.

Since your input signal traverses (relative to ground) between the values \$1.6\:\text{V}\$ and \$2.0\:\text{V}\$, and accepting your statement of a hysteresis bandwidth of \$100\:\text{mV}\$, I believe your hysteresis values should located at \$1.75\:\text{V}\$ and \$1.85\:\text{V}\$.

You conveniently possess access to \$3.3\:\text{V}\$ and \$0\:\text{V}\$, as well as the comparator output itself (or opamp output.) This is three voltage sources and suggests immediately the use of three resistors in the form of a resistor divider, whose shared node output can either be \$1.75\:\text{V}\$ and \$1.85\:\text{V}\$ depending on the comparator/opamp output.

So I'd get this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq30rj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course, this assumes the loading is all-around acceptable to you. But the relative values of the resistors is the important part. (I've rounded to nearer standard values, so the exact thresholds are just slightly different.) The output needs to be able to approach the rails, though. So keep that bit in mind. Also note that this doesn't require odd voltage sources. It simply relies upon \$V_\text{CC}=+3.3\:\text{V}\$.

Comment: Thanks team,I changed the reference now it is working fine